# How to cancel svn for a netbeans project

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-6.9, visualsvn

At first time,I set the project at a wrong place.I wan't to cancel it and do it again.What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete all of the .svn can do this trick

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "cancel", but you should be able to point NetBeans to a new repository and folder and start again.

Since this is Subversion, you can always blow away your working copy completely and start fresh.

Comment: thank you.Cancel is for start fresh.But the point is I don't know how to do it in netbeans